# How can I get added row textfield text when tapping button?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have added extra row in table view for particular category, i need that added row textfield finalSearchValue while tapping button.

i am having two textfields `cell?.searchTextfield.text = alertParam`(this is Mobile Number getting from json)and `cell?.searchTextfield.text = "Amount"` (added extra row Amount) if i enter text in this two textfields i need that two values in two variables, in payButton how to achive that.

[image]

i have taken like this;

```
var cell : BillerTableViewCell?
var finalSearchValue : String = ""
var finalSearchValueAmnt : String = ""
```

if i enter amount value in finalSearchValueAmnt, and phnum in finalSearchValue, i need these two values, but i am getting only last textfield value, why? please help.

here is the code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

if indexPath.section == 0 {

    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textfieldCell", for: indexPath) as? BillerTableViewCell
    cell?.searchTextfield.delegate = self

    if self.rowCount! - 1 >= indexPath.row
    {
        if let customerDetail = selectedBiller?.bcustomerparms[indexPath.row] {

            alertParam = customerDetail.paramName
            cell?.searchTextfield.text = alertParam
            if var priceOfProduct: String = customerDetail.minLength {
                alertMinL = Int(priceOfProduct)
            }
            if var priceOfProduct: String = customerDetail.maxLength {
                alertMaxL = Int(priceOfProduct)
            }
            cell?.searchTextfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchPhoneEditingChanged(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)
        }
        else{
            print("no tf")
            cell?.searchTextfield.text = "missing"
        }
    }
    else{
        cell?.searchTextfield.text = "Amount"
        cell?.searchTextfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchAmountEditingChanged(textField:)), for: .editingChanged)

    }
  }
  return cell!
  }


@objc func searchEditingChanged(textField: UITextField) {
    finalSearchValue = textField.text!
    self.textCount = self.finalSearchValue.count
}

@objc func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
if self.finalSearchValue.isEmpty{
        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter \(self.alertParam!)", in: self)
    }
    else if self.textCount ?? 0 < self.alertMinL ?? 0{
        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "\(self.alertParam!) not lessthen \(self.alertMinL!)", in: self)
    }
    else if self.textCount ?? 0 > self.alertMaxL ?? 0{
        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "\(self.alertParam!) not graterthen \(self.alertMaxL!)", in: self)
    }
    if self.finalSearchValueAmnt.isEmpty{
        AlertFun.ShowAlert(title: "", message: "Please enter Amount", in: self)
    }
    else{
    billerFetchService()
    }    
    }
```

How can i get `cell?.searchTextfield.text = "Amount"` finalSearchValue in one variable, please help me in the above code.

Comment: could you reduce your code as much as possible, so that only the problem you are having remains?

Comment: @TomášPospíšek, i have edited my question please help me in code

Comment: you already store the `finalSearchValue = textField.text!` value in finalSearchValue, you can use same variable inside buttonClicked method. what was the issue?

Comment: indentation of the code seems to be broken. (I'm a programmer, but not a swift programmer, but I see that your code is very complicated, hard to read, so I'm trying to help you by making you make your code easier to read and reduce it to the minimum. That way the problem can stand out more clearly)

Comment: `cell` is undefined outside `if indexPath.section == 0 {}`, so does this even compile?

Comment: @SGDev, i have edited question, i am getting only one value, i need two values please help

Comment: @koen, i have edited question, how can i get two values

Comment: cell is still undefined.  And if it was defined in `let cell = tableView.deque... `it wouldn;t be optional and there'd be no need to optional chain `cell?.`. You need a cell to return whatever you are doing, so create it before doing anything else in the method.

Comment: Where do you attach the `buttonClicked` function, right now it is never called. Please read [ask] and provide a [example].

Comment: I think it would be also helpful to see how the tableCell looks like to understand what you are trying to achieve. I personally can't imagine, what you are trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: @Maverick2805, i have two textfields , i need that two textfield vales in button

Comment: @flanker, updated cell, i have two text fields in cell, i need those two textfieldfinal values in two variable to send JSON post parameter

Comment: @SwiftIos: please add a picture to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @SGDev, updated code please help

Comment: @koen, added image and question, i need mobilenum and amount values in payButton

Comment: @SwiftIos check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem : How to get values from textfield.

Solution : i have create a two action method. one for Phone Number and 2nd for amount.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

if indexPath.section == 0 {

    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "textfieldCell", for: indexPath) as? BillerTableViewCell

    if self.rowCount! - 1 >= indexPath.row
    {
        if let customerDetail = selectedBiller?.bcustomerparms[indexPath.row] {

            alertParam = customerDetail.paramName
            cell?.searchTextfield.text = alertParam 
    cell?.searchTextfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchPhoneEditingChanged(textField:)), for: .editingChanged) // for phone number 

       }

    }
    else{
        cell?.searchTextfield.text = "Amount"
    cell?.searchTextfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchAmountEditingChanged(textField:)), for: .editingChanged) // for amount

    }
} 
return cell!
 }
```

// Action Method

```
@objc func searchPhoneEditingChanged(textField: UITextField) {
    finalSearchValue = textField.text! // used to store phone Number
    self.textCount = self.finalSearchValue.count
}

@objc func searchAmountEditingChanged(textField: UITextField) {
    finalSearchValueAmnt = textField.text! // used to store Amount.
}
```

// retrieve both values

```
@objc func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
  //Now here you can get both the values.
  print(finalSearchValueAmnt)
  print(finalSearchValue)

 }
```

Comment: once please look at my `buttonClicked ` what i did mistake here, if there is no added row means only one row then also it says please enter amount, why?

Comment: if there is only one row then i dont need amount